# Anchor links can't affect two elements - is there a workaround to jump on both the title and text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, tumblr

I'm a novice with a slight background in HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I'm modifying a tumblr theme to suit my preferences. The title and description are both in two separate CSS elements. The description has a scrollbar (in case the javascript does not work for some reason), and the title bar does not. I grabbed the jquery code from another available theme. I would like the links to jump to specific places in the title and description simultaneously.

The code currently hides the non-linked description. However, if javascript wasn't working, it would be fine to just have it jump to a place in the text instead. The thing is, I would like the title to jump with the anchor link as well (which is otherwise not scrollable).

Here is the code formatting (I removed the extra styling from the copy/paste.) I generally understand the code, but would not know how to (or want to) recreate the CSS elements from scratch.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
 
#main {
    width: max(562.5px, 45vw);
    margin-top: 10vh;
}

.pgtitle {
    width: max(540px, 43.2vw);
    height: 26.5px;
    padding: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pgtitle ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 
.infobox {
    width: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    height: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    float: left;
}
 
.infoboxicon {
    padding: max(14.0625px, 1.125vw);
    width: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    height: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    display: block;
}
 
.infoline {
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    padding: max(4.5px, .36vw) max(11.25px, .9vw);
    width: max(152.5px, 12.176vw);
    height: max(20.5px, 1.64vw);
}

 
.biobox {
    float: right;
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    padding: max(14.0625px, 1vw);
    width: max(337.5px, 27vw);
    height: max(281.28px, 22.5vw);
    overflow: auto;
}
 
}
.biobox ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 
#linkbox {
    width: max(562.5px, 45vw);
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    height: max(58.5px, 4.68vw);
    float: right;
}
 
#linkbox a {
    margin: 0 max(2.25px, .18vw);
    padding: max(2.25px, .18vw) max(7.875px, .63vw);
}

#linkbox ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

<div id="main">
 
<div class="pgtitle">
    <ul>
        <li id="t1" class="title-content">Title 1
        <li id="t2" class="title-content">Title 2
    </ul>
</div>
 
<div class="infobox">

<img class="infoboxicon" src="">
</a> 
  
<div class="infoline">1</div>
<div class="infoline">2</div>
<div class="infoline">3</div>
 
<div class="infoline">1</div>
<div class="infoline">2</div>
<div class="infoline">3</div>
 
</div><!--infobox-->
 
<div class="biobox">

<ul><!--anchor links-->
    <li id="d1" class="tab-content"><!--Link 1-->
        Link 1 Description

    <li id="d2" class="tab-content"><!--Link 2-->
        Link 2 Description

</ul>
 
</div><!--biobox-->
 
<div id="linkbox">
    <ul id="tabs-nav">
        <a href="#d1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#d2">Link 2</a>
    </ul>
</div><!--linkbox-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {
  $('.title-content:not(:first), .tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
   $('#tabs-nav a').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $(this.hash);
    $('#tabs-nav a.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("normal", function () {
        $this.addClass('current');
        $target.fadeIn("normal");
    });
  }).filter(':first').click();
});
});
</script>
   
</div><!--main-->
```

This is the original code if that's helpful: https://pastebin.com/jbsCrSiP 
This is the static preview: https://yukoki-th.tumblr.com/tsunkei

I'm new to this forum, so sorry if I did this wrong. Thank you to anyone who replies!!

Answer (score 0):

Do not hide the description in css but do it with javascript.
So when JS is not working, description is not hide.

And here is a correction on the JS you provided.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
   ///
});
```

are the same thing, don't need to double check.
[JQuery Document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.title-content:not(:first), .tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
    
    $('#tabs-nav a').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $target = $(this.hash);
        $('#tabs-nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("normal", function () {
            $this.addClass('current');
            $target.fadeIn("normal");
        });
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Also in HTML, you forgot all the `</li>`, you put `<a>` in `<ul>`, you must autoclose the `<img/>`, `</a>` is not valid, use `</a>`...

So many errors! Look at the corrected snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.title-content:not(:first), .tab-content:not(:first)').hide();

    $('#tabs-nav a').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $target = $(this.hash);
        $('#tabs-nav a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content:visible').fadeOut("normal", function () {
            $this.addClass('current');
            $target.fadeIn("normal");
        });
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
 
#main {
    width: max(562.5px, 45vw);
    margin-top: 10vh;
}

.pgtitle {
    width: max(540px, 43.2vw);
    height: 26.5px;
    padding: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.pgtitle ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 
.infobox {
    width: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    height: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    float: left;
}
 
.infoboxicon {
    padding: max(14.0625px, 1.125vw);
    width: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    height: max(157.5px, 12.6vw);
    display: block;
}
 
.infoline {
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    padding: max(4.5px, .36vw) max(11.25px, .9vw);
    width: max(152.5px, 12.176vw);
    height: max(20.5px, 1.64vw);
}

 
.biobox {
    float: right;
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    padding: max(14.0625px, 1vw);
    width: max(337.5px, 27vw);
    height: max(281.28px, 22.5vw);
    overflow: auto;
}
 
}
.biobox ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
 
#linkbox {
    width: max(562.5px, 45vw);
    margin-top: max(11.25px, .9vw);
    height: max(58.5px, 4.68vw);
    float: right;
}
 
#linkbox a {
    margin: 0 max(2.25px, .18vw);
    padding: max(2.25px, .18vw) max(7.875px, .63vw);
}

#linkbox ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div id="main">
  <div class="pgtitle">
    <ul>
      <li id="t1" class="title-content">Title 1</li>
      <li id="t2" class="title-content">Title 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="infobox">
    <img class="infoboxicon" src="" alt="find something to say about the image"/>
    <a/> 
    <div class="infoline">1</div>
    <div class="infoline">2</div>
    <div class="infoline">3</div>
    <div class="infoline">1</div>
    <div class="infoline">2</div>
    <div class="infoline">3</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="biobox">
    <ul>
      <li id="d1" class="tab-content">Link 1 Description</li>
      <li id="d2" class="tab-content">Link 2 Description</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="linkbox">
    <ul id="tabs-nav">
      <li><a href="#d1">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#d2">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I also recommand you to try upgrading the jquery you use, at least on the same major version. See the [JQuery CDN](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the reply!! I thought there was a </li> but for some reason the code worked without it, so my brain skipped over it. I really appreciate all the corrections and explanations too!

I'm not sure you answered my initial question though? Right now the javascript is only connected to the #d1, #d2. Thinking on it more, I realize I don't need the javascript on the #t1, #t2 (since it's already hidden by the overflow). I just need those to jump as anchor links as well. However, the actual links can only connect to one anchor link each? So is there another way to do this?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, you may have answered my question - albeit backwards. So with the description I could have it use anchor links, but for the titles, I could hide and unhide them with CSS? I know that can easily be done with javascript (without using anchor links), but I wonder how to hide/unhide elements in correspondence with a link using only in CSS?